# What is there for a service tier that can access SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I've never built anything to work with a service between my Windows Forms Application and SQL Server. Now I have a need to.

Anyone have suggestions on where to start? Or if there is a simple way to convert my Windows Forms Application to run on a service?

**Some background and information on what I have learned so far:**

**Background**

I have been building an client server application (.Net 4.5) for work that accesses SQL Server as the server part (2008 or 2012).

Now corporate has come down saying that SQL Server can not be 'open' on the internet, we need a service to run and that service can have access to SQL Server.

We are the only division, in a large company, that has software that clients access themselves.

The old application was FOXpro and had to work hard to keep things multiple users working etc.  A choice was made to use SQL Server Express, but while our clients were OK with having Foxpro on systems, but not OK installing SQL Server Express (might lose 10-20% of clients). My boss was hoping to host the databases for our clients using SQL Server and that is the development path we have been on for a year. I've recently added Entity Framework (version 5) to the application, but not all of it is built using it (maybe 5% uses EF), I think I can move all of it fairly quickly if that helps in finding a solution.

**Learned so far**

I've glanced at a bunch of stuff but all of it uses OData services and that would appear to make current client application code all be worthless. Basically it looks like I need to build a ASP.Net web application instead of my Windows Forms application that we have over $100K invested in.

Clearly this can't be the case and I am missing something. But after about an hour on the internet I have begun to freak out. I'm not clear on if I can use OData to create my Windows Forms client application, if so how that might look. Everything I see on OData points to building web applications.

**Just a little more background** 300-500 installed users - about 200-300 databases/clients (all clients have their own database).

**update 7/25/2013**
When I say each client has own database, I mean each client will have a database on our server.  No self service was planned.  Old way was self service, new why not self service.
**end update 7/25/2013**

**Question, again**
Anyone have suggestions on where to start? Or if there is a simple way to convert my application to run on a service?

Comment: OData can be consumed by ***any*** kind of application. Yes, most samples are web apps - but there's absolutely nothing stopping you from issuing a HTTP request from a Windows Forms app, and getting results back to shown them in a Forms gridview or something.

Comment: There is likely no simple method, but typically IIS is used to host a web service that exposes access to your database. You can additionally have the web service perform functionality that might be done by the client (bandwidth-intensive queries and computation) and present those end-results to the client. Are your clients joined to domains, and do you have trust for those domains? If not, I suspect a web service is the most secure way to deploy your service.

Comment: We don't have trust for the domains @AaronFriel

Comment: @marc_s Examples? Because I have not found any.

Comment: WCF.  Which is the key word to a big world.  If your current code has a clean separation between your Presentation Layer and your Business Layer......and you return either DTO's or Xml or DataSets to your presentation layer...you'll be able to pull it off.  If you have too much business logic in your presentation layer or (heaven forbid) datalayer calls in your presentation layer.....you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @granadaCoder I'm in world of hurt (I didn't build most of it, i'm 4th programmer in 12 months).

Comment: Ouch. @granadaCoder is spot on, given your needs and a lack of trust, WCF is your best bet.

Comment: Here is an older example.  It uses "Type Sharing" (not just Data-Contract Sharing).........it could be useful.  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/wcf-with-interface-development/

Comment: I love how companies don't think they need some kind of architect for their software.  Then wonder why the maintenance costs are so high.

Comment: @granadaCoder the link to getting started is not valid anymore.

Comment: It worked for me.  The "thoughtworks" link in the article is dead.  But my blog link and the downloadable code is still working.

Comment: http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2007/10/18/wcf-with-interface-development/

Answer (score 1):

1. You will have to chose which type of data transfer objects you are going to pass across the wire.  Traditionally, this has been DTO (Data Transfer Objects), (in strictly dotnet world) DataSets (which are just fancy xml's), or Xml.....and add JSON in there.
2. You services will expose Methods.  So instead of talking to Sql Server, you talk to the service.  Your client-app should have zero knowledge of what kind of RDBMS you have chosen.
3. I would pick WCF.  "Web Api" is a new thing as well.  Some see it as the replacement or upgrade to WCF.  I kinda think they made Web Api because WCF can be complicated because there are so many options.  Configuration in WCF is the "magic", once you get it right, its fine, but getting there can be a hassle sometimes.
4. If you go with WCF, and your client(s) are only DotNet clients, then I would use Type-Sharing.  That is my first option.  I only move away form Type-Sharing when I think there may be a real possibility that I might have a non DotNet Client.
5. I would read this older article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817644(pandp.10).aspx

And if you throw in "Json" to their list of "What to pass around", you'll get a slightly clearer good grasp this idea of "what I'm passing around".  "Business Entity" to them means DTO or POCO object.

1. If you original application followed the good practices of #5 above, then you should be able to pull off  Type-Sharing WCF.  I'm not saying it's "cut and paste", but it is do-able.
2. If your "architecture" does not resemble good separation of layers and separation of concerns, you're in a world of hurt.  If the original code has SqlConnection riddled in and out of everywhere, you're in a world of hurt.

Bad design up front costs a company 10 fold, 100 fold, 100,000 fold in the end.
No idea why some people don't get this.

Good luck dude.

Pitfalls:
"Just wire up some Web Service asmx pages".  That is a common "patch".  It's very 2003'ish.  That's not the correct approach in 2013.

Comment: I found this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx and think it shows a lot of what you are saying, agree?

Comment: That is if you want the "straight up data".  And as mentioned by marc_s "OData can be consumed by any kind of application.".  I'm not sure that's what you want.  You pay a price if you want your services to work with non dot net clients.  That is needed alot of times, but not every time.  I would mentally map it like this.  If you already have a "business layer" in your application, and that's the place you want to focus on replacing, you can replace that with a wcf SERVICE. if u have a "data layer" in your application, and that is the primary thing you want to replace, then consider the OData

Comment: Now I think I am completely lost.

Comment: I am building an application that clients will install.  So I control that, strictly dotnet world.  There are no layers in this application.  Frankly it is a poor design from top to bottom, but with over 100K into the design and deadline 2 months away, it is not getting fixed any time soon.

Comment: Right.  So even if clients install it.....they don't want the client-application having direct access to the sql server.  They want a layer of protection.      WCF service.  In 2 months?  Youch.  This is why all my new projects start out as a WCF service.  Much easier to dumb it down to a monolithic app later, then service up in the future.     I don't envy you dude.  Good luck.

Comment: When I say each client has own database, I mean each client will have a database on our server.  No self service was planned.  Old way was self service, new why not self service. - edited question with this info.

Comment: //100K into the design//   The cost of software is not the initial development, but ongoing maintenance costs.  That's a lesson learned the hard way.........after being in this game for a long time.  Good luck dude.  Sounds like you're in a tough situation.  Don't kill yourself over it.